# Joomla 2.5 custom authentication plugin using OpenID

Tags: authentication, plugins, joomla, openid, joomla2.5

I have been trying for many days to create a custom authentication plugin using OpenID for Joomla 2.5. I first used this extension: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-cloud-based/5366. It has a CAS plugin, but no OpenID plugin. I tried to use the CAS login plugin format for OpenID but my level of joomla/php/openid/cas knowledge is insufficient and it does not work.

I have also tried to use some available libraries such as lightopenid. It works on a custom-built website based on php, but I have tried to apply it to Joomla 2.5 with no success.

The next alternative is to use Janrain's OpenID (which was used in Joomla 1.5 actually). I am in the process of adapting the code from Joomla 1.5 to 2.5.

Has anyone been able to successfully develop a custom authentication plugin using OpenID for Joomla 2.5? Which of the above methods would you recommend? I do not want to use 3rd party apps such as Social Login and Social Share (which currently works), but to have it in-built into the normal Joomla login module.

Hope to be able to receive some help in developing such a plugin.

Comment: Here is some background on how OpenId got removed and the issues that it has: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/joomlabugsquad/re_7yUYp4zI

Comment: Thank you for the link! Didn't think it was this tough to implement OpenID...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla! 1.5 has a default-installed plug-in which allow user to log-in with open ID. In Joomla! 2.5 this plugin is not installed.

If you want to use OpenID Authentication and if you want a free extension you can download it from here: http://socialjoom.net.ru/component/option,com_jdownloads/Itemid,75/cid,46/task,view.download/ .

ALSO you can simply install Social Login extension:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-cloud-based/20465 . It's commercial...

All extensions are here: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-cloud-based

PS: I haven't tested these extensions.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have tried the extensions and they allow me to successfully login via OpenID. However, it shows up as an icon which users have to click, and then enter their OpenID URL in full. I was hoping to have a form inbuilt into joomla whereby users can just type their ID (and it will append it to the back of the OpenID server URL). After reading a bit of the background on why OpenID was removed after v1.5, it really looks quite tough to implement. I'll continue to work on it and perhaps one day publish an OpenID extension on Joomla's extension website..

Comment: If you have any other questions, do not hesitate to contact me!

Comment: Ok! @LeeHe . Yes, you must have 15rept to be allowed to +1, but you can set as correct answer. Check this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/226739 If you have any other questions, do not hesitate to contact me, I'm happy to help you with OpenID integration!

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of using an external authentication system (login page) instead joomla login page/module, is due to make sure that the access is secure and make possible to left a session cookie to allow single-sing-on if you are in an internal environment in wich webs/apps log through this external authenticator, so navigate to a login page from the authentication system is an standard.
If you want to use API OIDC calls to make your joomla login works with the authenticator, in this case, your credentials were exposed to risks/hacks and you couldn't get SSO between applications.